# zcart nginx configuration + htaccess conversion

Tags: laravel, apache, .htaccess, nginx

Please help me to convert zcart application's htaccess rules to nginx configuration. Please see below htaccess.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are already configure your FastCGI part of config, lets try:

```
# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]
```

can be converted to nginx configuration as

```
location ~ ^(.+)/$ {
    if (!-d $request_filename) {
        return 301 $1;
    }
    # else this is a directory, will be processed via index file in this directory by default
}
```

or (the same result)

```
location ~ ^(.+)/$ {
    if (!-d $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^(.*)/$ $1 permanent;
    }
    # else this is a directory, will be processed via index file in this directory by default
}
```

---

```
# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

will be processed by a single `try_files` directive in the main `location` block:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
```

---

And, finally,

```
# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

requires no additional config in `nginx.conf`, because `$_SERVER[HTTP_AUTHORIZATION]` variable will be appended to `$_SERVER` array automatically when HTTP `Authorization` header is set (if your php-fpm configuration correct).